# connect mysql with heroku and deploy, pinterestclone- on github. can someone help me understand

Tags: javascript, mysql

-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
!     Push failed

its what heroku says when i deploy. https://github.com/filipljung/pintrestclone- to see to full code. greatful for feedback!

......................

Comment: Please read [ask] and create [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.